# Why console log on library doesn't work, when it has been imported to a different react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a library 'some-library' where i have written a console.log("message from some library") statement in 'some-component.js'. I have used uglifyjs in this library with default settings. When I import 'some-component' from 'some-library' i do not see 'message from some library'. 
Request you to please help me in this?

I have tried with npm link, it doesn't work. Manually copy pasted the libraries(pretty similar to link) in the calling component. But doesn't work. Whereas if i put the source code of the library in the calling component. I see the message.

Comment: Link the `some-library`’s npm page so we can check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, got this sorted. I had used sumologic library and had replaced console log instead of augmenting it. The issue is now sorted.